# Parse dynamic String into HostPreference

Tags: haskell, haskell-warp

Using the [Warp library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.11/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#v:readsPrec), the `setHost` function will not accept a dynamic `String` as a host value, however it will be perfectly happy with a string literal:

```hs
> import           Network.Wai.Handler.Warp

> apiHost = "0.0.0.0" :: String
> getHost $ setHost (read apiHost) defaultSettings
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

> getHost $ setHost apiHost defaultSettings
<interactive>:16:19: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘HostPreference’
      Expected type: HostPreference
        Actual type: String

> getHost $ setHost "0.0.0.0" defaultSettings
Host "0.0.0.0"
```

All works fine when the value is a string literal, but I couldn't find any way to make it work when it's a string dynamically generated. Which is exactly what I need, because the host value comes from an environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you found an answer for this library specifically, but there is a more general solution.  You were able to use a string literal because HostPreference is an instance of the [IsString](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString) class (and you have the OverloadedStrings extension turned on).  That means you have the `fromString` method of that class available, so `fromString (read apiHost)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out... as usual, [Hoogle is our friend](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=String%20-%3E%20HostPreference&scope=set%3Astackage).

```hs
String -> HostPreference

-- first result:
-- Host :: String -> HostPreference
-- streaming-commons Data.Streaming.Network.Internal
```

And from there

```hs
> import           Data.Streaming.Network.Internal (HostPreference (Host))

> apiHost = "0.0.0.0" :: String
> getHost $ setHost (Host apiHost) defaultSettings
Host "0.0.0.0"
```